# Vb .net Webbrowser Control, Trigger Angular JS Validation on a Web Form

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am using VB .Net to fill in forms on a webpage that I do not have control over. They use angularjs. I currently am able to programmatically set the value for all of the textboxes in the form, but there is a dropbox that no matter how I try selecting a value, it never causes the validation on Angular's side so it keeps the default value when the form submits. What could i be doing wrong, or what can I do to force the validation to take place on the box after I set the value?

Here is the code on their webpage (I cut out some of the values so it wouldn't be so long):

```
<select name="reservationModel.pickUpTime" ng-if="!vm.isModal()" ng-model="vm.reservationModel.pickUpTime" ng-options="time.value as time.minits for time in vm.times" required-error-message="err.global.requiredPickUpTime" class="form-control res-inputTime ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" aria-label="Pick Up Time">
    <option label="11:30 AM" value="string:11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
    <option label="noon" value="string:12:00 PM" selected="selected">noon</option>
    <option label="12:30 PM" value="string:12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
    <option label="1:00 PM" value="string:1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
    <option label="1:30 PM" value="string:1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
    <option label="2:00 PM" value="string:2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
</select>
```

What I have tried (element is the main select element and ele is the option element that matches the value I want)

```
element.InvokeMember("click")
element.RaiseEvent("onchange")
ele.Focus()
ele.SetAttribute("selected", "selected")

element.SetAttribute("value", "string:1:00 PM")
element.SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
element.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 26)
ele.InvokeMember("onchange")
element.InvokeMember("onchange")
ele.RaiseEvent("onchange")
element.RaiseEvent("onchange")
```

Here is what the element changes to if you manually change the dropdown box on the website:

```
<select name="reservationModel.pickUpTime" ng-if="!vm.isModal()" ng-model="vm.reservationModel.pickUpTime" ng-options="time.value as time.minits for time in vm.times" required-error-message="err.global.requiredPickUpTime" class="form-control res-inputTime ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" aria-label="Pick Up Time">
```

Comment: I already changed the tags for your question, since I noticed that the syntax is AngularJS, but in your question I now noticed that you mention Angular 2... which is it really? :)

Comment: Is the `select` the last element you change before submitting the form?  If your code is fine, perhaps validation hasn't had time or requires some other event like a select blur.  Just a long shot but see if it helps to do the select first and then blur the field or modify one of the other inputs before submitting.  Just a thought.

Comment: I believe it's AngularJS. I don't know why I said angular2. That was a mistake.  Also as to trying select first I've changed the order or added and removed different lines to see if t works. It seems that ng-prestine doesn't change to ng-dirty and ng-untouched doesnt change to ng-touched if I set them using a program. I need some type of better way to simulate typing so that the validation gets executed in the background.

Comment: Also the on change or select function does not submit the form. There is a separate function I have that clicks on submit. It submits the form but leaves the drop down box at the default value no matter how I change it programmatically. That is because some hidden variables get set when the validation runs. If there is a way to manually set the flags for ng-dirty and my-touched then it may actually work.

Comment: I had a similar problem. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207999/using-webbrowser-to-automate-filling-in-an-angularjs-form/43220977

Comment: @Aximili that works perfectly in the web console for google chrome but it doesn't seem to work in vb .net. I am using this code. `WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("angular.element($(""select[name='reservationModel.pickUpTime']"")).val('string:1:30 PM').triggerHandler('change')")`