# Using WebBrowser to automate filling in an AngularJS form

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, webbrowser-control

I am using WebBrowser to automate filling in a textbox, on a website that uses AngularJS.

This is the HTML on their website

```
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="login.email" autofocus="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-touched" aria-invalid="false">
```

This is my C# code

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("email")[0].SetAttribute("value", _login);
```

That populates the input box, but I don't think it updates the Angular model.
Hence you can't submit the form because that website **(ie. Angular) thinks it is still empty**.

How do you trigger the ng-model update from my WebBrowser control?

Comment: You using angularJs1.x or Angular2?

Comment: It seems to be Angular1 from the HTML, but I'm hoping the solution can be applied to any similar framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the script needed to update ng-model

```
angular.element($("input[name='email']")).triggerHandler('change')
```

and you can execute it from WebBrowser like this

```
wb.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "angular.element($('input[name=email]')).val('your@email').triggerHandler('change')" });
```